# How do I set the value of a sequence in Postgres to max(value) + 1 for that table?

Tags: postgresql

I created a table with a SERIAL column but I also manually inserted some rows. I need to update the SERIAL so it goes to the next one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your sequence is named `$seq`. If you used the `SERIAL` to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE foo {id SERIAL, .... }
```

the sequence would be called something like `foo_id_seq`

Do this:

```
SELECT setval('foo_id_seq', (SELECT max(id) FROM foo), TRUE)
```